# What is these objects in powershell (1GB, 11GB, ...)

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, you have some magic suffixes for numbers. Ie, you can prefix any number with `MB`, `GB`, `TB`, and alike, and they will return the amount in bytes.

Example;

```
PS C:\> 1TB
1099511627776

PS C:\> 123KB
125952
```

What exactly is this black magic? They show up as type `INT`;

```
PS C:\> (123GB).getType() | ft -AutoSize

IsPublic IsSerial Name  BaseType        
-------- -------- ----  --------        
True     True     Int64 System.ValueType
```

With the same basetype as normal INT's

```
PS C:\> ([int]123).getType() | ft -AutoSize

IsPublic IsSerial Name  BaseType        
-------- -------- ----  --------        
True     True     Int32 System.ValueType
```

So the questions remains;

- What exactly are these "things"?
- How can I create my own.
- Where/how can I get a list of other magic prefixes I can use?
- Will they ever be correct? (ref kibibyte vs kilobyte (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte))

Comment: They are not "things". They are a part of the language syntax for numeric literals. See the [language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9706) §2.3.5.1.3 "Multiplier suffixes" - I've linked to the v2.0 spec, but it's the same in all subsequent versions

Comment: Gee, if "everything is a thing" then these things are "things" after all!  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What exactly are these "things"?**

They are known as "administrative constants".

**How can I create my own.**

I don't believe you can.

**Where/how can I get a list of other magic prefixes I can use?**

You have everything from Kilobyte to Petabyte (KB, MB, GB, TB, PB).

**Will they ever be correct?**

They will always be the 2^n version - I don't think of that as incorrect though...

> Yes, the PowerShell team is aware that these notations are not consistent with the IEC recommendations (kibabyte, and so on). Since the point of this notation is convenience and most people in the IT space are more comfortable with Kb than with Ki, we choose to err on the side of comfort over conformance in this one case. Sorry. This particular issue generated easily the second most heated debate on the PowerShell internal and external beta tester lists.
>                                   ~ Bruce Payette, Powershell in Action

You can use `1e3`, `1e6`, etc. to get "standard" Kilo, Mega, etc.

```
$> 12345 / 1e3
12.345
```

Comment: Aren't you mixing them up here? Kibibyte is 1024 bytes.. 12345/ 1e3 = 12.345 Kilobytes (10^3). 1KB in powershell is 1024 byte = 1 Kibibyte, but the PS-team decided to use KB as that's what people say (1000bytes is one kB).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It still feels a little random that these constants are focused on storage. But I guess thats just what they have implemented.

Comment: Random? Well, PowerShell is a scripting language for computer automation, so KB, MB etc. are very important and frequently used values. What are you missing?